# Settings to access printer are not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, crystal-reports

This is my configuration to print my report:

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings printersettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
printersettings.PrinterName = Printer;
printersettings.Copies = 1;
printersettings.Collate = false;
reporte.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Report/Client/CustomInfo.rpt"));
reporte.SetDataSource(ds);
reporte.PrintToPrinter(printersettings, new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings(), false);
```

The print name is correct at this point. (Debugging proved the name is correct and the document has the correct path.) But I still getting this error:

> Settings to access printer 'Xeroxprinteroffice' are not valid.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Drawing.Printing.InvalidPrinterException:
>   Settings to access printer 'XeroxPrinterOffice' are not valid.

This occurs in line: `reporte.PrintToPrinter(printersettings, new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings(), false);` How can I resolve this?